# How can I deploy a Laravel package via filezilla?

Tags: laravel, server, web-deployment, laravel-nova, filezilla

I'm working on a Laravel project. I installed Laravel Nova via

```
php artisan
```

and integrated to the project locally. I know how to deploy files, but I don't know how should I deploy this package to the server via filezilla. I hope my question is understandable enough.

Of course there is no log which I can run

```
php artisan nova:value.........
```

to install it on the server.

Comment: As far as I know, running commands requires ssh access to the server. Can you use your ftp credentials(or other credentials) to access ssh?

Comment: You need to have SSH access to the server, of course you could zip the application and upload it but that is 100% not what a 1 person business does. Use GIT and AWS/DigitalOcean or anything similar to do deployments, as normal devs do

Comment: Yes, I have SSH access. but where/how do I run the commands?

Comment: In the root of your project like you did locally

Answer (score 0):

**To deploy a Laravel package via FileZilla, you will need to do the following:**

Connect to your server via FTP using FileZilla.

Navigate to the root directory of your Laravel project on your server.

Drag and drop the package files from your local machine to the new folder on your server.

In your Laravel project's root directory, open the `composer.json` file and add the package to the "require" section.

Run the command `"composer update"` on your server to install the package and its dependencies.

Finally, run the command `"php artisan config:clear"` and `"php artisan config:cache"` to clear the config cache and update your application.

Comment: If he can run commands, he can surely run composer install, no need to create a directory

Comment: So is this answer still valid?